# Innosetup cannot import default functions

Tags: inno-setup, freepascal

i built an installer with [InnoUltra 5.5.1](http://innoultra.ru/) (a improved version of InnoSetup)
It work fine for most of users, but there is one that has this error when starting the exe:

[image: error]

His configuration is:

- Windows 7 Pro SP1 version 64 bits
- wot path folder => K:\Games\World_of_Tanks
- .NET Framework  version => 4.5.2

I tried releasing 64bit but nothing,
I also checked dependecies of the installer and the only warnings are:

- GPSVC.DLL
- IESHIMS.DLL
  (should be fine)

Seems that default functions are not founded, any solutions?

Comment: As your version differs from original one try to run the setup in Debug environment to see what is happening. Maybe missing parameter or some system variable?

Comment: do you mean inside inno setup compiler software? yes, i don't have any erorrs.. this happens only to one user